# Simultaneous measurement of the size and mass of nanoparticles in liquid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, optics, fluid-dynamics, nanoscience

The size of colloidal nanoparticles in a liquid can be measured from optical reflectance (or absorption) spectra. The smaller the metal (semiconductor) nanoparticle, the more its color shifts to the red (blue) side. Is it possible to simultaneously measure both the size and mass of a nanoparticle (not necessarily by optical methods)?